# Nginx reverse proxy variables and resolver

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to set up reverse proxy with a wild card on both ends, eg. `test.example.com` to `test.local`, etc. So far I have this and it is working.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name ~^(?<project>.+)\.example\.com$;

        location / {
                resolver dns.local;
                proxy_pass http://$project.local/;
        }
}
```

But, no other files get served anymore, eg. when I request `test.local/style.css` I just get the same index again.

Thank you!

Comment: Neat idea.  Can you drop `debug` level logs for a request into your question?  That should have enough detail to see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long! Here is the log http://pastebin.com/hEyfNcm2